# ab: Could not read POST data file: End of file found

Tags: post, apachebench

I am getting the error in the title when trying to run Apache Bench to test a HTTP endpoint I wrote, but *only* when specifying a POST file with contents. If I specify an empty file to `-p`.

I have been trying various solutions found online regarding the encoding and format of the contents, but it seems like just about any content will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when installing Apache Bench from source, I had copied over the `ab` executable file from `httpd/support/bin/.lib/ab` to `~/.local/bin`. When I did that, it used the system-wide `libapr` instead of the one I had downloaded to `httpd/srclib/apr`. This caused some sort of version mismatch, I assume.

The solution was to remove my copy of ab from `~/.local/bin` and instead create a script `~/.local/bin/ab` with contents

```
#!/bin/sh

$SRC/httpd/support/ab "$@"
```

and make this executable with `chmod a+x ~/.local/bin/ab`.